# Как построить график по данным, полученным в консольном приложении?

Tags: график, vba, c++, visual-studio, visual-basic

Коллеги, помогите, пожалуйста!

Есть консольное приложение, которое в результате расчетов получает значения и записывает их в текстовый файл! Нужно по этим значениям построить графики любым образом. Как сделать лучше, т.е. менее трудозатратно?

Варианта в общем всего два своих: прикрепить через vba или построить в той же Visual C++. Соответственно сразу вопросы:

- если VBA, как построить парсер, может у кого-то есть примеры;
- но лучше в VC++, и тут тоже вопрос: как из меню консольки запустить проект построения графиков, будет ли это просто функция,запускаемая после отработки функций консоли или отдельное решение, которое надо как-то прикрепить и тоже вызвать.

Направьте, пожалуйста, на путь истинный!

Comment: Это проще сделать через встроенный в С# graph control, там вроде даже есть встроенный экспорт из .csv, не помню точно. Главное не пытайтесь проделать это через самостоятельно рисуя график через picture box. 90% времени при таком подходе вы будете пытаться его правильно смасштабировать/выровнять

Comment: текстовый файл на выходе из консоли, и к сожалению с# вообще ноль((

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - это генерировать [.csv](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) файл. Его можно открыть любым excel'ом и тут же, не задумываясь построить график (мастер диаграмм, график, точечный и т.д.). Стоит только помнить об ограничении Excel'а на число ячеек (по-моему 65535). Я это ограничение обходил, генерируя на выходе значения **в заданном диапазоне** и с определенной **степенью детализации**.

Comment: По всей видимости, @igumnov предложил что-то аналогичное, но если я все правильно понял, он видимо перепутал экспорт с импортом )

Comment: не задумываясь не получится, вывод идет ряда значений строкой типа
    fout<<n<<" "<<countS<<" "<<countP;
соответственно, вывод ряда посчитанных значений идет идет в одну ячейку, а графики нужны к примеру, обоих каунтов от n. снова встает вопрос как построить парсер на vba..

Comment: т.е. имеется 3 значения: n, countS и countP, и нужно построить 2 графика зависимостей **n/countS** и **n/countP**?

Что мешает выводить их одновременно, в 2 колонки?
т.е.

 fout<<n<<";"<<countS<<";;"<<n<<countP

Comment: А если в первой строке исходных данных указать текстовые значения, к примеру "x" и "y", то **excel** вынесет их в легенду.

Comment: дааааа!!!в этом и был вопрос, спасибо большое!!!не знала как разделить по колонкам выводимые данные!

СПАСИБО!